# How do i resolve module not found errors in mongodb after node upgrade to v18?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, serverless

I'm getting these warnings after upgrading the node version from 16 to 18, can anyone please tell me what is the fix for these warnings? Do i need to add these dependencies to project?

Package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@7eleven/7boss-logger": "^1.2.2",
    "@7eleven/7boss-mongo-util": "^2.5.0",
    "@7eleven/7boss-objects": "^2.0.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1506.0",
    "joi": "^17.11.0",
    "lambda-api": "^0.10.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.3",
    "aws-sam-webpack-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "serverless": "^3.38.0",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^6.4.4",
    "serverless-offline": "^13.3.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that some packages are not compatible with your current `NodeJS` version (18).
Try running your application with `docker` to maintain the runtime environment.
Another alternative is to use `nvm` (Node version manager) where you can easily install and switch between different Node versions seamlessly.  [Check it out](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: My requirement is to upgrade the node version to 18 or higher. It might work with lower node versions.

Comment: If you wish to upgrade, you should make sure that your new node version meets the minimum requirements for the packages that you use for your project.